# Creating a "choice" variable that indicates what choice was taken, by assigning the column name - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to create a "choice" variable that indicates what choice was taken among some alternatives.
The alternatives in this example are: 123, 456, 789.
If there is no choice, assign 0 value, if there is multiple choice, assign a 1 value,
otherwise, assign the choice name (by taking the column name).

Data illustration:

```
ID  Date        X   123 456 789
A   07/16/2019  ..  1   0   0
A   07/19/2019  ..  0   0   0
A   07/20/2019  ..  0   1   0
A   07/22/2019  ..  1   0   0
A   07/23/2019  ..  0   1   1
B   07/27/2019  ..  0   0   1
B   07/28/2019  ..  0   0   0
B   07/30/2019  ..  0   0   0
```

Expected result:

```
ID  Date        X   123 456 789 choice
A   07/16/2019  ..  1   0   0   123
A   07/19/2019  ..  0   0   0   0
A   07/20/2019  ..  0   1   0   456
A   07/22/2019  ..  1   0   0   123
A   07/23/2019  ..  0   1   1   1
B   07/27/2019  ..  0   0   1   789
B   07/28/2019  ..  0   0   0   0
B   07/30/2019  ..  0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
#seelct last 3 columns
df1 = df.iloc[:, -3:]
#sum 1 values
s = df1.sum(axis=1)
#set values by conditions
df['choice'] = np.select([s == 1, s == 0], [df1.idxmax(axis=1), 0], default=1)
print (df)
  ID        Date   X  123  456  789 choice
0  A  07/16/2019  ..    1    0    0    123
1  A  07/19/2019  ..    0    0    0      0
2  A  07/20/2019  ..    0    1    0    456
3  A  07/22/2019  ..    1    0    0    123
4  A  07/23/2019  ..    0    1    1      1
5  B  07/27/2019  ..    0    0    1    789
6  B  07/28/2019  ..    0    0    0      0
7  B  07/30/2019  ..    0    0    0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a ways to do it by selection, using a custom function which does the job and [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
#list with the names of valid alternative columns
alternatives = ['123', '456', '789']

#custom function to do the selection
def pick_choice(row):
    ones = row[alternatives].loc[row[alternatives] == 1]
    if len(ones) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(ones) > 1:
        return 1
    elif len(ones) == 1:
        return ones.index[0]

df['choice'] = df.apply(pick_choice, axis=1)
```

Resulting `df` is:

```
  ID        Date   X  123  456  789 choice
0  A  07/16/2019  ..    1    0    0    123
1  A  07/19/2019  ..    0    0    0      0
2  A  07/20/2019  ..    0    1    0    456
3  A  07/22/2019  ..    1    0    0    123
4  A  07/23/2019  ..    0    1    1      1
5  B  07/27/2019  ..    0    0    1    789
6  B  07/28/2019  ..    0    0    0      0
7  B  07/30/2019  ..    0    0    0      0
```

Careful that `dtype` of column `'choice'` is `object` and not `int`, because column names are strings (even if you have integers).